# Text in field disappears when text length is longer than width of the field

Tags: html, css, svg, input

## **Disappearing Text**

Problem: Text in one of my fields is disappearing when the length gets too long.

2 text fields, 1 with text longer than the width of the field, the lower with text shorter than the field. The top field behaves correctly with longer text, the bottom does not.

[image: text field with short text]

The lower text field now has 2 extra characters added to push the length of the text past the width of the field itself (but does not look like it). All of the text has disappeared.

[image]

Only seeing this issue with the bottom field, all other fields on the page work properly when longer text is entered.

**May be important: These fields are in an SVG**

The field that behaves properly.

[image]

```
<g transform="translate(0,5)rotate(0)skewX(0)scale(1,1)" data-fieldid="a66cbb44-4c62-5036-9af7-d42d2d54ea1a" data-fieldname="Customer Contact" class="field" id="field-4d0c86b9-ba1a-6887-33d6-4831b91675b4" data-name="customerContact" data-columnname="customerContact" data-altcolumnname="customerContact" data-cssclass="k-textbox" data-datarole="" data-editable="true" data-fieldgroup="Header" data-label="Customer Contact" data-placeholder="" data-size="128" data-sort="1" data-style="" data-type="text" data-value="" data-jsonobject="" data-validationsize="0" data-businesslogic="[]" percentage="0.0014492753623188406" percentagewidth="0.7101449275362319"><path d="M0 0 L 245 0 245 50 0 50Z" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="0" fill="transparent"></path><text style="font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; font-family: sans-serif; display: none;" x="0" y="14" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,62.5,17)" fill="#2e2e2e">Customer Contact</text><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="211.0434782608696" height="50" style="position: relative;"><div style="position: static;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="fieldLabel" style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px;">Customer Contact </div><br><span class="inputWrapper" data-inputtype="text" style="width: 211.043px;">
    <input name="customerContact" maxlength="128" type="text" class="svgInput k-textbox" data-bind="value: formData.customerContact, disabled: isEventDisabled">
</span><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="customerContact"></span></div></foreignObject></g>
```

The field where the text disappears.

[image]

```
<g transform="translate(0,65)rotate(0)skewX(0)scale(1,1)" data-fieldid="674ec495-c094-543a-a2e5-eb8582d4be82" data-fieldname="SalesOrderNotes" class="field" id="field-74a59816-f070-46d3-5239-c2033be30de7" data-name="salesOrderNotes" data-columnname="salesOrderNotes" data-altcolumnname="salesOrderNotes" data-cssclass="k-textbox" data-datarole="" data-editable="true" data-fieldgroup="Header" data-label="SalesOrderNotes" data-placeholder="" data-size="2000" data-sort="1" data-style="{&quot;style&quot;:{&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#000000&quot;},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;fieldType&quot;:&quot;no&quot;}}" data-type="text" data-value="" data-jsonobject="" data-validationsize="0" data-businesslogic="[]" percentage="0.0014492753623188406" percentagewidth="1"><path d="M0 0 L 345 0 345 45 0 45Z" stroke="#808080" stroke-width="0" fill="transparent"></path><text style="font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; font-family: sans-serif; display: none;" x="0" y="14" stroke="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,115.5,14.5)" fill="#2e2e2e">SalesOrderNotes</text><foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="298" height="45" style="position: relative;"><div style="position: static;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="fieldLabel" style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; font-size: 14px;">SalesOrderNotes </div><br><span class="inputWrapper" data-inputtype="text" style="width: 298px;">
    <input name="salesOrderNotes" maxlength="2000" type="text" class="svgInput k-textbox" data-bind="value: formData.salesOrderNotes, disabled: isEventDisabled">
</span><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="salesOrderNotes"></span></div></foreignObject></g>
```

As far as I can tell, they match in CSS and HTML markup. Any requests for other screenshots or info and I can post more information.

Edit:

I have noticed that the text in the field does not follow the translate that is set on the g element when it is too long.

Translated down 5.

[image]

Translated down 15. Text doesn't follow field here.

[image]

So when the original translate of 65 is applied, no text is visible.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers or just one? Also pleas post code as text, not images.

Comment: Looks like it does not have this issue in firefox. Our supported browser is Chrome.

Comment: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: Could you perhaps avoid putting inputs into the SVG itself and just use native text fields?

Comment: They need to be in SVGs, we use SVGs to draw and design our forms.

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker, I provided the link above.

Comment: I experience the same problem. Do you have any news on the issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Has anyone figured anything out about this issue?

Comment: This is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347671/text-input-box-as-foreignobject-within-an-svg-text-overflow-issue . It is a bug in chrome, but it was fixed in the latest canary build (I tested 4/11/18 and it worked). This means eventually stable chrome will have the fix, but probably not for a while